# How to find process life duration via windbg

Tags: windbg

I am trying to find out for how long the process was running before it crashed. Is it possible to find this information from the dump.

Answer (score 2):

Use the .time command.  I know this works on live targets and I believe it works on dumps as well.

Answer (score 1):

Time spent sleeping isn't charged against thread times.